# Covering Get/Set in Apex Test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write code to cover a class that was written by someone else. It appears as though the class is used by other classes to provide a JSON Wrapper for data that is passed into it.

The class is

```java
public class dataJSONWrapper {
    public Schema schema {get;set;} 
    public List<Data> data {get;set;} 
    public String DocType {get;set;}

    public class Schema {
        public List<Fields> fields {get;set;} 
        public List<String> primaryKey {get;set;} 
    }
    
    public class Data {
        public Integer index {get;set;} 
        public String FileName {get;set;} 
        public String Label {get;set;} 
    }
    public class Fields {
        public String name {get;set;} 
        public String type {get;set;} 
    }
}
```

How do I provide coverage for this?

In a previous question I was told to do something like this:

```java
@isTest
public class OrderCreationJSONWrapperTest {
    @isTest
    public static void TestSchema {
        Boolean primaryKey = dataJSONWrapper.Schema.primaryKey;
    }
}
```

But obviously I got something wrong. I am getting an error message

> "Unexpected token 'Boolean'.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the class, you will see that the type of that field is `List<String>` not Boolean and you will need an instance. So this will compile:

```
dataJSONWrapper w = new dataJSONWrapper();
List<String> primaryKey = w.schema.primaryKey;
```

but will fail at runtime as `w.schema` will be `null`. In Apex tests you have to first create the data structure before testing it.

Note that there is no value-add writing a test for simple data holders like this. Perhaps more useful to write a higher level test that serializes to JSON and deserializes from JSON.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C.  I was afraid of that. I will have to trace back to what is calling these and build the data from there.

Comment: Actually @Keith C id did not compile. I got an error message "Unexpected token 'dataJSONWrapper'." I probably have a syntax error somewhere but not sure where it would be.

Comment: Hi @JonathanCrow, Normally you will get a specific line number reported to so go to that line...

Comment: Hi @Keith C, the line is the one you provided. dataJSONWrapper w = new dataJSONWrapper();

I just have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @JonathanCrow And you put that line as the first line of the `TestSchema` method?

Comment: Yes. This is the complete test class so far (at signs removed from isTest for posting here):
isTest
public class dataJSONWrapperTest {
    isTest
    public static void TestSchema {
     dataJSONWrapper w = new dataJSONWrapper();
  List<String> primaryKey = w.schema.primaryKey;
 }
}

Comment: Got it. I didn't add the () after the test method. Should be: isTest public static void TestSchema () {